# NSPredicate use with Array with multiple objects

Tags: objective-c, search, nspredicate, predicatewithformat

I have an app that correctly uses NSPredicate to filter an array and displays the resulting filtered array to the user.

Here is my NSPredicate code:

`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Name CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (Acronym CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (departments.Name CONTAINS[cd] %@)",searchBar.text,searchBar.text,searchBar.text];`

The problem comes when the user attempts to search by the `departments.Name` property. I believe the problem is the way that I search through the array (ListData). The way that the array is formatted is:

The ListData array holds several objects with keys: Name, Acronym, and departments (which further has objects with a key: Name). I want to use NSPredicate to search through the ListData.Name, ListData.Acronym, AND ListData.departments.Name.

**NOTE:** There are a range of 0-10 departments which an object could contain. Not sure if this would cause any problems, but I would like to provide as much relevant information as possible.

How would I format the `NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:` to search all three variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `departments` is an array of objects, then you can use `ANY` in the predicate:

```
 ... OR (ANY departments.Name CONTAINS[cd] %@)
```